# How to change color of bars in a PGFPlots bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I've got a bar chart with a couple of bars.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
        xbar, xmin=0,
        xlabel={Percantage \%},
        symbolic y coords={{Bar 10}, {Bar 9}, {Bar 8}, {Bar 7}, {Bar 6}, {Bar 5}, {Bar 4}, {Bar 3}, {Bar 2}, {Bar 1}},
        ytick=data,
        yticklabel style={text width=7cm, align=right, font=\footnotesize},
        bar width=20pt,
        height=0.9\textwidth,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (4,{Bar 10})
        (4,{Bar 9}) 
        (20,{Bar 8}) 
        (22,{Bar 7}) 
        (29,{Bar 6}) 
        (30,{Bar 5}) 
        (32,{Bar 4}) 
        (35,{Bar 3}) 
        (39,{Bar 2}) 
        (43,{Bar 1}) 
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: monochrome bars]

Now I want to highlight some bars, like Bar 1 and Bar 3.
However when changing the plots like this:

```
\addplot coordinates {
    (4,{Bar 10})
    (4,{Bar 9}) 
    (20,{Bar 8}) 
    (22,{Bar 7}) 
    (29,{Bar 6}) 
    (30,{Bar 5}) 
    (32,{Bar 4}) 
    (39,{Bar 2}) 
};
\addplot coordinates {
    (35,{Bar 3}) 
    (43,{Bar 1}) 
};
```

The result ends up like this:

[image: multicolor broken bars]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That not all bars have `yticklabel` is because of `ytick=data` which only adds `yticks` and the corresponding labels at the coordinates of the **first** `\addplot` command. Instead use `ytick distance=1`.

The strange looking second `\addplot` command is because the bars are placed **next** to each other at the coordinate. And because the bars are very wide it seems that they are placed at another coordinate. So you need to disable the "next to each other placement" with `/pgf/bar shift=0pt`.

```latex
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        xmin=0,
        xlabel={Percantage \%},
        symbolic y coords={{Bar 10}, {Bar 9}, {Bar 8}, {Bar 7}, {Bar 6}, {Bar 5}, {Bar 4}, {Bar 3}, {Bar 2}, {Bar 1}},
%        ytick=data,             % <-- this caused the missing entries
        ytick distance=1,       % <-- added
        yticklabel style={text width=7cm, align=right, font=\footnotesize},
        bar width=20pt,
        height=0.9\textwidth,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        /pgf/bar shift={0pt},   % <-- doesn't place bars next to each other
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (4,{Bar 10})
            (4,{Bar 9})
            (20,{Bar 8})
            (22,{Bar 7})
            (29,{Bar 6})
            (30,{Bar 5})
            (32,{Bar 4})
            (39,{Bar 2})
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (35,{Bar 3})
            (43,{Bar 1})
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]